# Pass in ID from previous view/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have been fighting this for a while.

I have a simple app that use users, timesheets and entries.  timesheets belong to to users and an user has many time sheets.  Entries belong to time sheets.

A user can click on a time sheet and be presented with the entries from that time sheet.  I can create entries in the rails console and they show up correctly. But I am having trouble inserting the correct timesheet ID on the entries.

I may not be doing this correctly, but I have a link on the time sheet view to the entry view.  I am having trouble bringing over the time sheet id to insert it in the the create entry view.

I am using a form_for that looks like this.

```
<%= form_for(:entry, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Subject form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:order_number) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:time_in) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:time_out) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Time Sheet ID</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:time_sheet_id, :value => @sheet_id ) %></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Add Entry") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

**This is my entry controller.**

```
   def create
        @time_id = TimeSheet.find(1)
        @new_entry = Entry.new(entry_params)
        if @new_entry.save
          flash[:notice] = "New Entry has been Added!"
          redirect_to(:action => 'index')
        else
          render('new')
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do instead:

```
@new_entry = time_id.build_entry(entry_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I Am closing this.

It was poorly worded and I figured out the problem.

All I needed to do is run the form_for from my timesheets controller and redirect it to the entries controller.